# UITableView scrolls beyond the bounds of my uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

In my view, I added another view (named popupview) for custom popover like animation.

In the popupview, I have added a table view and have set some bounds to the table view, but the table view height doesn't change, whatever height I set in the xib.

There is another problem that when scrolling in the tableview, it scrolls out of the view even if the tableview is inserted in the popup view.

There are no issues with the image I have used. It has the same height, width as the second uiview popupview.

**XIB Structure:**

View1 mainView - table view

[image: View 1]

View2 PopupView {Orange View}

[image: View 2]

TableView2 - table in popup view

[image: TableView 2]

Comment: set fram programmatically :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the "popupview" view's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`. This should prevent the "sticking out" of the table-view, if the frame of the table-view is greater/not the same as the frame of your "popupview".

But aside from that, the proper way:

Have you experimented with the Autosizing/Autoresizing-Mask settings of your views?
Your table-view is a subview (i.e. child) of your popupview, right?
so the table-views frame should scale (i.e. autoresize) to the parrent views frame (popupview)!
You can configure this behavior either in IB in the "Size Inspector" pane of your table-view or programmatically. You should check out the [View Programming Guide for IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html).

Comment: I think the behavior changed at some point. The current default behavior for tableViews is for clipsToBounds to be false. I would suggest setting clipseToBounds on the tableview rather than the popup if you don't want the cells to extend past the designed table.